# Error when trying to update database entries using html form

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I have a character database that displays certain information.  When I click "Update Information" it takes me to an HTML form where I'm allowed to update the current information.  When I fill in the new information and hit "Update", I get the following error:

**Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /home3/tarb89/public_html/aususrpg.net/charbase/updated.php on line 59
Binding parameters failed: (0)**

Here is my update.php code:

```
<?php
    // Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE id = '$id'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>

<form id="FormName" action="../charbase/updated.php" method="post" name="FormName">
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Name: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["name"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="picture">Avatar: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["picture"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Breed: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["breed"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Gender: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["gender"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Height: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["height"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Age: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["age"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Parent 1: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["sire"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Parent 2: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["dam"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Children: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["children"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Status: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["status"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Player: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["player"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Body Type: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["bodytype"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Genetics: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["genetics"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Base Color: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["basecolor"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Eye Color: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["eyes"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Mane Color: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["mane"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Tail Color: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["tail"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Patterns: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["patterns"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Facial Markings: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["face"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Leg Markings: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["legs"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Body Markings: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["bodymark"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Extras: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["extras"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Trait 1: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["trait1"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Trait 2: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["trait2"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Trait 3: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["trait3"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Trait 4: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["trait4"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Trait 5: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["trait5"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Trait 6: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["trait6"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Defect 1: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["defect1"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Defect2: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["defect2"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Defect 3: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["defect3"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Defect 4: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["defect4"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Defect 5: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["defect5"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Defect 6: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["defect6"] ?>"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td width="300" align="right"><label for="name">Player Notes: </label></td>
<td><input name="name" maxlength="255" type="text" value="<?php print $row["notes"] ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input name="" type="submit" value="Update">
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

And here is my updated.php code:

```
<?php 
// Your database info 
$db_host = 'xxx'; 
$db_user = 'xxx'; 
$db_pass = 'xxx'; 
$db_name = 'xxx';

// POST data
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$picture = trim($_POST["picture"]);
$breed = trim($_POST["breed"]);
$gender = trim($_POST["gender"]);
$height = trim($_POST["height"]);
$age = trim($_POST["age"]);
$sire = trim($_POST["sire"]);
$dam = trim($_POST["dam"]);
$children = trim($_POST["children"]);
$status = trim($_POST["status"]);
$player = trim($_POST["player"]);
$bodytype = trim($_POST["bodytype"]);
$genetics = trim($_POST["genetics"]);
$basecolor = trim($_POST["basecolor"]);
$eyes = trim($_POST["eyes"]);
$mane = trim($_POST["mane"]);
$tail = trim($_POST["tail"]);
$patterns = trim($_POST["patterns"]);
$face = trim($_POST["face"]);
$legs = trim($_POST["legs"]);
$bodymark = trim($_POST["bodymark"]);
$extras = trim($_POST["extras"]);
$trait1 = trim($_POST["trait1"]);
$trait2 = trim($_POST["trait2"]);
$trait3 = trim($_POST["trait3"]);
$trait4 = trim($_POST["trait4"]);
$trait5 = trim($_POST["trait5"]);
$trait6 = trim($_POST["trait6"]);
$defect1 = trim($_POST["defect1"]);
$defect2 = trim($_POST["defect2"]);
$defect3 = trim($_POST["defect3"]);
$defect4 = trim($_POST["defect4"]);
$defect5 = trim($_POST["defect5"]);
$defect6 = trim($_POST["defect6"]);
$notes = trim($_POST["notes"]);


$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($con->connect_error)
{
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE characters SET name = ?, picture = ?, breed = ?, gender = ?, height = ?, age = ?, sire = ?, dam = ?, children = ?, status = ?, player = ?, bodytype = ?, genetics = ?, basecolor = ?, eyes = ?, mane = ?, tail = ?, patterns = ?, face = ?, legs = ?, bodymark = ?, extras = ?, trait1 = ?, trait2 = ?, trait3 = ?, trait4 = ?, trait5 = ?, trait6 = ?, defect1 = ?, defect2 = ?, defect3 = ?, defect4 = ?, defect5 = ?, defect6 = ?, notes = ? WHERE id = ?"; 
if (!$result = $con->prepare($sql))
{
    die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);
}

if (!$result->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssi', $name, $picture, $breed, $gender, $height, $age, $sire, $dam, $children, $status, $player, $bodytype, $genetics, $basecolor, $eyes, $mane, $tail, $patterns, $face, $legs, $bodymark, $extras, $trait1, $trait2, $trait3, $trait4, $trait5, $trait6, $defect1, $defect2, $defect3, $defect4, $defect5, $defect6, $notes, $id))

{
    die('Binding parameters failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}

if (!$result->execute())
{
    die('Execute failed: (' . $result->errno . ') ' . $result->error);
}

$result->close();
$con->close();
echo "Entry updated.";
?>
<br>
<a href="../login">Return to index page.</a>
```

I'm a pretty big novice at PHP so I'm not quite sure what's wrong here.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: how are you binding all these variables with only 'si' if (!$result->bind_param('si', $name, $id, $picture, $breed, $gender, $height, $age, $sire, $dam, $children, $status, $player, $bodytype, $genetics, $basecolor, $eyes, $mane, $tail, $patterns, $face, $legs, $bodymark, $extras, $trait1, $trait2, $trait3, $trait4, $trait5, $trait6, $defect1, $defect2, $defect3, $defect4, $defect5, $defect6, $notes)). you have 35 variables, but with the 'si' in the bind you're telling mysqli that you're binding only 2

Comment: Should I completely remove the 'si' or change it to something different?  I had help building this code so I'm not even completely sure what the 'si' even means.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the values you're passing to `bind_param()` versus the question marks in `prepare()`. I can see at a glance that `$id` is in the wrong place. The error message says the count is wrong as well.

EDIT: something like this in PDO would save you having to count question marks. Totally untested; may not even parse but should point you toward an easier to work with solution.

```
<?php 
// Your database info 
$db_host = 'xxx'; 
$db_user = 'xxx'; 
$db_pass = 'xxx'; 
$db_name = 'xxx';
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
$expected_posts = array(
    "id", "name", "picture", "breed", "gender", "height", "age", "sire", "dam", "children",
    "status", "player", "bodytype", "genetics", "basecolor", "eyes", "mane", "tail", "patterns",
    "face", "legs", "bodymark", "extras", "trait1", "trait2", "trait3", "trait4", "trait5",
    "trait6", "defect1", "defect2", "defect3", "defect4", "defect5", "defect6", "notes"
);
$posts = array();
foreach ($_POST as $k=>$v) {
    if (in_array($k, $expected_posts)) {
        $posts[$k] = trim($v);
    }
}

$sql = "UPDATE characters SET name=:name, picture=:picture, breed=:breed, gender=:gender, height=:height, 
age=:age, sire=:sire, dam=:dam, children=:children, status=:status, player=:player, bodytype=:bodytype, 
genetics=:genetics, basecolor=:basecolor, eyes=:eyes, mane=:mane, tail=:tail, patterns=:patterns, 
face=:face, legs=:legs, bodymark=:bodymark, extras=:extras, trait1=:trait1, trait2=:trait2, 
trait3=:trait3, trait4=:trait4, trait5=:trait6, trait6=:trait7, defect1=:defect1, defect2=:defect2, 
defect3=:defect3, defect4=:defect4, defect5=:defect5, defect6=:defect6, notes=:notes WHERE id=:id";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($posts);
?>
```

Comment: I switched the $id around.  The above commenter said that the 'si' was the issue.  I re-counted everything and it all matches up.

Comment: That also. You need an "s" for each string parameter, and an "i" for each integer. This is much easier in PDO, where you just pass the parameters as an array to the exec function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssi', $name, $picture, $breed, 
$gender, $height, $age, $sire, $dam, $children, $status, $player, $bodytype, $genetics, 
$basecolor, $eyes,  $mane, $tail, $patterns, $face, $legs, $bodymark, $extras, $trait1, 
$trait2, $trait3, $trait4, $trait5, $trait6, $defect1, $defect2, $defect3, $defect4,
$defect5, $defect6, $notes, $id)
```

for each string that you want to bind you add an `s`, and for each integer you should add an `i`. I am not sure my types are right check them and modify any `s` to `i` if it is actually an integer that you're updating with.

Here is a link to learn more:

http://jp.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: I no longer get the error, but it doesn't actually update anything now.  I switched it to if (!$result->bind_param('isssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss', $id, $name, $picture, $breed, $gender, $height, $age, $sire, $dam, $children, $status, $player, $bodytype, $genetics, $basecolor, $eyes, $mane, $tail, $patterns, $face, $legs, $bodymark, $extras, $trait1, $trait2, $trait3, $trait4, $trait5, $trait6, $defect1, $defect2, $defect3, $defect4, $defect5, $defect6, $notes)) as the only true integer is the ID field.

Comment: id should be at the end, you should follow the order of the `?`

Comment: `if (!$result->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssi', $name, $picture, $breed, $gender, $height, $age, $sire, $dam, $children, $status, $player, $bodytype, $genetics, $basecolor, $eyes, $mane, $tail, $patterns, $face, $legs, $bodymark, $extras, $trait1, $trait2, $trait3, $trait4, $trait5, $trait6, $defect1, $defect2, $defect3, $defect4, $defect5, $defect6, $notes, $id))` is what i changed it to, and now it says "entry updated" when in reality it completely deletes the entry from the database.  Sorry for being such a pain, but is there a specific reason why it's doing that?

Comment: deletes the entry!!! are you sure! stop pasting code in comments pls, update your question at the place

Comment: I checked my phpmyadmin.  It does not delete the entry per say - the row is still there with the ID number.  However, it deletes all of the other information and it is completely blank.  It's not inserting the information into the database like it should.  I apologize for posting code in the comments.  My question is now updated to reflect the changes.

Comment: are you sure, your variables contain values? I don't think the problem is still from the query but more from the variables

Comment: I have a feeling it's the question marks in the SET query - after hitting "update" the question marks should be replaced by the information inputted into the HTML table.  I have a feeling i don't have it coded correctly; so for example, instead of name = ? it should be something like name = $formnameinput or something similar.  I guess I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: No that's not the best solution, if you are learning it is better to learn prepared statements with binding.  U didn't tell me are u sure your vars have values